# Как добавить в autoload-composer'a свои скрипты?

Tags: php, composer

Начал осваивать `composer`, и сразу возник вопрос. Для подключения установленных библиотек, мы в начало скрипта добавляем файл `composer'a autoload.php`.

Я почти в каждом своём скрипте вверху подключаю файлы config.php и functions.php.

*Вопрос*: возможно ли как то добавить это всё в auloload и в каждом скрипте ограничится только лишь подключением autoload.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть несколько способов сделать это используя Composer: Указывать перечень классов в разделе classmap, перечислять файлы в секции files или же настроить правило psr-4:

```
"autoload": {
   "classmap": [
        "services/myserv/Ksl.php"
   ],
   "psr-4": {
        "Services\\": "services",
        "liw\\": ""
   },
   "files": [
        "config.php"
   ]
}
```

Подробнее можно почитать тут https://klisl.com/composer_autoload.html